# SVD versus RSVD

Tags: recommender-system, svd, matrix-decomposition

In the so-called incremental SVD used for collaborative filtering:
http://www.machinelearning.org/proceedings/icml2007/papers/407.pdf
http://www2.research.att.com/~volinsky/papers/ieeecomputer.pdf
http://www.quuxlabs.com/blog/2010/09/matrix-factorization-a-simple-tutorial-and-implementation-in-python/

The user-item matrix $R$ is factored as $P^{T}Q$ using gradient descent. In the classical SVD there is the diagonal matrix $S$ which holds the singular values. What happens(ed) to that matrix in this formulation? Is it just omitted and they still call it SVD or is it implicitly part of $Q$ and/or $P$ ?

Answer (score 2):

The diagonal matrix **S** which represents the amount of information stored in that feature its "inside" of **P** and **Q**. You can think the SVD like **R** = **U** * **S** * **Vt** or **R** = **U** * **S^(1/2)** * **S^(1/2)** * **Vt**, where also you can(should) truncate the diagonal matrix S, in order to capture the information and ignore the noise in the data, a good number in the bibliografy (Practical Recommender Systems Kim Falk) is around 90%

Comment: Hello, Carlos, and welcome to the site!  It's a fine answer, but you really should learn Mathjax (easy to do) for formatting math stuff.

Comment: Thx for the advise! Next time I will implement that tool for sure